# Reshaping my data frame and adding a flag

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
df <- 
ID   TIME   IPREDP   IPREDM
1     0.5    10        5
1     1.0    15        7
2     0.7    8         2
```

I want to reshape my data and collapse the `IPREDP` and `IPREDM` columns into one column called `IPRED` and add a flag called `DVID` for each and get rid of the original `IPREDP` and `IPREDM` columns. So the output should be this:

```
dfout <- 
ID    TIME    DVID    IPRED
1     0.5     1       10
1     0.5     2       5
1     1.0     1       15
1     1.0     2       7
2     0.7     1       8
2     0.7     2       2
```

How can I achieve this in R in the fastest possible way?

Comment: With tidyr and dplyr, `df %>% gather(DVID, IPRED, IPREDP:IPREDM) %>% mutate(DVID = as.integer(factor(DVID, levels = c('IPREDP', 'IPREDM'))))`

Comment: using library(reshape2), `melt(df,measure.vars =c("IPREDP","IPREDM"), value.name="IPRED")`

Comment: In base R - `reshape(df, idvar=c("ID","TIME"), direction="long", varying=3:4, v.names="IPRED", timevar="DVID")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(reshape2)
dfout <- melt(df,measure=c("IPREDP","IPREDM"), value="IPRED", variable="DVID")
dfout$DVID <- as.integer(dfout$DVID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   library("data.table") 
   df1 <- melt(df, id = c("ID", "TIME"), measure  = c("IPREDP", "IPREDM"), value.name = "IPRED")
   df1$DVID <- as.integer(df1$variable)
   df1[, variable := NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df), id.var = c("ID", "TIME"), value.name = "IPRED")[
          order(ID)][, DVID := 1:.N,.(ID, variable)][]
```